# Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event

Tags: mysql, warnings

After update of MySQL I started getting annoying warnings

```
Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly
```

How do I get rid of these?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're not using scheduled events you can ignore this message by adding

```
--events --ignore-table=mysql.event
```

to your commandline

You can find more details at
http://www.linuxbrigade.com/warning-skipping-data-table-mysql-event/

And more about MySQL Event Scheduler at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: If you are using them though, you would do just `--events` :) (that way they get included, so you get them with your e.g. dump so there is no reason for any warning :) )